# Unable to stop link blinking after clicked using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to stop blinking of the link "View" after clicking it using a JavaScript code:

css:

```
.blinking span {
    -webkit-animation: 0.5s linear infinite condemned_blink_effect; 
    animation: 1.5s linear infinite condemned_blink_effect;
}

@-webkit-keyframes condemned_blink_effect { 
    0% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    50% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    100% {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}

@keyframes condemned_blink_effect {
    0% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    50% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    100% {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

php and JS:

```
<?php  
echo "<tr >";
echo "<td width='150'> <a href='disdata.php?id=" . $dispReturn->dispID . "' class='blinking'><span> View </span> </a> </td> ";
echo "</tr>";
?>

<script>
    function stopBlinking(e) {
        e.currentTarget.classList.remove('blinking');
    }

    const blinking = document.querySelectorAll('.blinking');

    for (link of blinking) {
        link.addEventListener("click", stopBlinking);
    }
</script>
```

The JS code can't stop blinking of the link "view" after clicking it so my expectation is stoping the blinking effect after clicking the link by modifying my js code.

Comment: Because you don't post your JS-code we only could guess. Try it wiht an `onclick` event and remove the class `blinking`.

Comment: Did you debug this to verify the click handlers where added to the elements as you expected, and that the correct element is selected inside the handler function? And are you canceling the link default action using some additional code you have not shown us? Otherwise it likely just switches to a different page, and in that of course anything you did via JS on the _previous_ page doesn’t matter any more.

Comment: the link redirects to the another page and I have no any code that cancels the link default action

Comment: Why is it an anchor tag if you don't wish to redirect to another page?

Comment: You have an anchor that redirects to `disdata.php` and you mentioned that you want to stop the blinking animation in the anchor, but if you abandon the page, what is the purpose of stopping the blinking effect?. Your code is OK [and it works](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/L2cx3vh8/), please, reformulate your question, it seems that your requirements are not well explained.